# Can you call methods on object using JDBI, @BindBean, @SqlQuery annotations?

Tags: java, javabeans, jdbi

I am trying to call a wrapper method for an object in JDBI. The wrapper method does not corresponds to any field of the object, but rather normalizes(formats) it, and then returns a string. Following is my class -

```
Class Car {
   String make;
   String model;
   //...
   //getters for make and model

   //wrapper method
   public String getCarDescription(){
      return "Make: " + make + " Model: " + model;
   }
}
```

My questions is - Can I call getCarType() inside JDBI `@SqlQuery()` ? Like this -->

```
@SqlQuery("select * from car where car_description = :car.carDescription")
public abstract Car getCarDescription(@BindBean("car") Car car);
```

I tried doing this, but JDBI does not return the right results. Whats more frustrating, is that JDBI does not throw any error or say if it is ok(or not ok) to call method on an object in this fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, JDBI can bind to methods on an object which have the getter format. I have just created a simple [project](https://github.com/andremanuelbarbosa/SOQ48894145) where I have replicated this scenario. One thing I have noticed on the code provided is that the name of the bind annotation @BeanBind is not correct but instead should be @BindBean as:

```
@SqlQuery("select * from car where car_description = :car.carDescription")
Car getCarDescription(@BindBean("car") Car car);
```